# OpenMP pragma with a meaning: don't vectorize

Tags: openmp, vectorization, simd

I have a loop with a really low trip count where vectorization doesn't pay off, but the compiler vectorizes it nevertheless. Is there a portable way to tell a compiler not to vectorize a loop, an opposite of `#pragma omp simd`

Comment: AFAIK, no. The usual way is to disable some optimizations and this is compiler specific. That being said, you generally do not want that as the result is likely to be platform dependent too. This case occurs when a compiler heuristic fail to measure the cost of a solution properly. Reporting such issue could help compiler writer to improve heuristics.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a compiler that supports the OpenMP API version 5.1, then it should accept this:

```
#pragma omp simd if(simd:0)
for (...) { ... }
```

That should then disable vectorization for the loop associated with the `simd` construct.

See [simd Construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu49.html#x74-750002.11.5) in the OpenMP specification.

Comment: Very interesting. It works with GCC >=9.2 and Clang >=11.0. Unfortunately not yet with the last version of ICC (I guess this will be implemented soon since AFAIK the new versions of ICC are now based on Clang). Here is an example: https://godbolt.org/z/M5advh1d6 .

Comment: If you cannot use `#pragma novector` as workaround, I can get in touch with the Intel OpenMP compiler folks and ask them when they will implement it. Have you tried ICX yet?

Comment: PS: Just checked ICX and it also supports the `if(simd:0)` syntax and disables vectorization.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Intel's compiler names may be confusing you. `icc` is the "classic" non-LLVM based, compiler and will remain that. `icx` is the newer, LLVM based, compiler. Therefore you shoudl not expect LLVM features to appear in `icc`, but, rather, in `icx`.

Comment: Is there any documentation about what if(simd:...) actually does beyond the syntax explanation in the OpenMP standard

Comment: It says that on page 235 of the 5.2 specification document: "When an if clause is present and evaluates to false, the preferred number of iterations to be executed concurrently is one, regardless of whether a simdlen clause is specified."